# CSS overflow-y is not scrolling

Tags: html, css

I'm running into some problems with css as i learn by myself and im in need of some explanations if you can help me.

my css code:

```
html,body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    background: #fff;
    height:100%; 
}

#top {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow:  0px 1px 1px 0px #585858;
    z-index: 10;
}

.menuR {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
    color: #585858;
    font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.content {
    position:relative;
    top: 40px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 85%;
}

.header {
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 650px;
    font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: #585858;
    color: #FFF;
}

.tableContent {
    margin: auto;
    width: 670px;
    min-height: 80%;
    overflow-y: scroll; 
    font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: #F2F2F2;
}
```

as I add more content to the div with the class .tableContent the div is growing instead of scrolling.

Comment: post your html too..or else share a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/#run) with us..

Comment: probably because you didn't specify the width / max-width, so the container grows as you add elements in instead of adding scroll

Comment: you didnt specify height for .tableContent..

Comment: i did specify the min-height for .tableContent

Comment: Did you mean to specify `max-height` instead?

Comment: ahh.. i got it.. you are correct Lal.

Comment: i specify min-height instead of height...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wer90rdx/)

This is the CSS that i used to make it scrollable..

```
.scroll{
    height:50px;
    width:100px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

for a div scroll. I specified a height.

and see the difference when i use `min-height` in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wer90rdx/1/)

Comment: i could vote for your answer but i dont have enough reputation.. thank for your help.